# Dozer: Mapping Exception

Tags: dozer

I have the following beans that need to map, both with a `java.io.File` field:

```
class CvPDFRespBO {
private String rutPersona;  
private File cvPDF;
getter()...setter() 
}   

public class CvPdfSVSResp{
private String rutPersona;
private File cvPDF;
getter()...setter() 
}
```

But the map gives me the following error:

```
11:01:33,208 ERROR [org.dozer.MappingProcessor] (http--0.0.0.0-8085-1) Field mapping error -->
  MapId: null
  Type: null
  Source parent class: package.CvPDFRespBO
  Source field name: cvPDF
  Source field type: class java.io.File
  Source field value: /var/folders/g0/yvljc75d2vl9bvs57vd4_2qr0000gq/T/2003JC4E5C928C429A8E48541.pdf
  Dest parent class: package.svs.CvPdfSVSResp
  Dest field name: cvPDF
  Dest field type: java.io.File: org.dozer.MappingException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.io.File.<init>()
```

Any tips? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect dozer is trying to map the File object into a new instance of file, and transfer the fields over, however File doesn't have a no-arg constructor, and it's getting a bit confused.

I would recommend creating a custom converter and using that to map the File object.

http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html